# Sending an AJAX POST request

Tags: android, ajax, post

I'm writing an app that will interact with site. In that site authentication is trough AJAX POST request.How can i execute that request in my Android app?

Comment: You can check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028981/using-httpclient-and-httppost-in-android-with-post-parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to differentiate a bit here:

**AJAX** is only the technology that initiates an [HTTP Post Request](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP_POST) from the Client Browser to the website. In your case, you want to send that **HTTP Post Request** from your Java application.

First you have to find out which URL is requested and what key-value-pairs are send within that request, which you can do by analyzing the AJAX code or by using some browser plugin or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to show you the raw POST request. Then you can submit that request using e.g. Apache's `HttpClient` (already available in the Android SDK). For finding out how to do that, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065/1467115).

Comment: Helped me too, good to know that `HttpClient` is already available in Android. Can you tell whether it's supported on all API levels?

Comment: As of Android 6.0, [Apache's HttpClient is not supported anymore](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).