# how to post json from html page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a html which contains a submit button , when clicking on button i want to make a post request to a webserver.
What i want to send :

```
curl -X GET http://192.168.2.253:8080/server/getReportData/ -d '{"project":"voda1","startDate":"1-1-2016","month":"0","endDate":"10-1-2016","simType":"0","roming":"0","latitute":"","longitude":"","radius":"","Peak":"0","kpi":[201],"name":"wavenet"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json
```

what actully webserver got :

```
http://192.168.2.253:8080/getReportData/%20-d%20%7B%22project%22%3A%22voda1%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%22%22%2C%22month%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%22%22%2C%22simType%22%3A%220%22%2C%22roming%22%3A%220%22%2C%22latitute%22%3A%2220.077728%22%2C%22longitude%22%3A%2221.07728%22%2C%22radius%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22Peak%22%3A%220%22%2C%22kpi%22%3A%5B%22201%22%2C%22203%22%2C%22303%22%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22wavenet%22%7D
```

How to do it correctly.

Below Is my javascript for demo

JSONTest = function() {

```
var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");
var data1 = {"user" : "mushir"};

alert(data1);
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.2.253:8080/server/getReportData/?",
    method:'GET',

    data: JSON.stringify(data1),
    //data: { apiKey: "23462", method: "example", ip: "208.74.35.5" },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        switch (result) {
            case true:
                processResponse(result);
                alert(result);
                break;
            default:
                resultDiv.html(result);

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

};

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an AJAX POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290672/sending-an-ajax-post-request)

Comment: Make a POST request, not a GET! http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request