# Using HttpPost/Put with ContentType Java Apache

Tags: java, apache, http-post, httpclient

I have looked at many questions regarding this same problem and have tried many proposed solutions without success. The one located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028981/using-httpclient-and-httppost-in-android-with-post-parameters) seems the most relevant, as the comment by RedSonic answered why this isn't working.
I am trying to make a POST or PUT request to my server using Java's Apache library.

```
public static void put(String caseNumber,DefaultHttpClient httpClient)
        throws Exception {
    HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(
            "http://localhost:8888/servlet/example1/" + caseNumber);
    putRequest.addHeader("Version", version);
//      putRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", content);
//      putRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader("ContentType", content));
    putRequest.setHeader("Accept", accept);
    putRequest.setHeader("Date", date);

    List <NameValuePair> nvpsPut = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvpsPut.add(new BasicNameValuePair("group", jsonPostGroup));
    putRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvpsPut));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);

}
```

I have tried creating a separate entity and setting the entity's content type, then set the entity to the request. I've tried other things as well, **but I can't manage to get the request to have the content type that I want to be passed in without the parameters I'm attempting to send over going blank.**

Have also tried

```
HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut("http://localhost:8888/servlet/example1/" + caseNumber);
putRequest.addHeader("Version", version);
putRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", content);
putRequest.setHeader("Accept", accept);
putRequest.setHeader("Date", date);

BasicHttpParams bhp = new BasicHttpParams();
bhp.setParameter("test", jsonPostGroup);
putRequest.setParams(bhp);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);
```

Log:

```
BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:8888
DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost:8888
RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: PUT /servlet/example1/000001994 HTTP/1.1
wire - >> "PUT /servlet/example1/000001994 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Version: 1.1[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Content-Type: application/JSON[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Accept: vnd.siren+JSON[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Date: Wed Aug 21 15:30:00 EDT 2013[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Host: localhost:8888[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
wire - >> "[\r][\n]"
headers - >> PUT /servlet/example1/000001994 HTTP/1.1
headers - >> Version: 1.1
headers - >> Content-Type: application/JSON
headers - >> Accept: vnd.siren+JSON
headers - >> Date: Wed Aug 21 15:30:00 EDT 2013
headers - >> Content-Length: 0
headers - >> Host: localhost:8888
headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)
wire - << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
wire - << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=davwq58qgxr8yvyw7bfybbbv;Path=/[\r][\n]"
wire - << "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
wire - << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
wire - << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
wire - << "Server: Jetty(9.0.0.v20130308)[\r][\n]"
wire - << "[\r][\n]"
DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
headers - << Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=davwq58qgxr8yvyw7bfybbbv;Path=/
headers - << Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
headers - << Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
headers - << Content-Length: 0
headers - << Server: Jetty(9.0.0.v20130308)
ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: davwq58qgxr8yvyw7bfybbbv][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null]". 
DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@7842f3a9
BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

**Edit**: I have found a few other suggestions that I've tried. Such as setting the parameters on the httpclient instead of the request (which doesn't make much sense in this scenario) but I experienced the same issue.

**Edit 8/23**: I'm still able to pass parameters via the setting the Entity, and giving the entity a name + value pair. However, as mentioned, this hoses the content-type. Any more thoughts before I give up entirely?

Comment: First of all, you are overwriting your `HttpEntity` by calling `setEntity()` a second time. Request parameters are not an entity. You can use the `setParams(HttpParams)` method of `AbstractHttpMessage` (ie. by inheritance `HttpPost`) to pass request parameters.

Comment: Sorry, the first setEntity was a leftover when I was trying a bunch of different things. I'll edit that out now. I had tried setParams originally without success. I just attempted again, and will add that code to the original question.

Comment: What you have in your second code snippet seems like it should work. Try to enable logging and check what is sent and what isn't. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android).

Comment: I enabled logging, and it doesn't mention the name or the value for the BasicHttpParams. It also mentions that content-length is equal to zero. I don't see anything in the log that says why, but I'll try and figure it out. I tried posting the log, but it formats really poorly. Not sure if you have any suggestions for that.

Comment: If you edit your code, in the banner above the text box, there are `{}` code braces. Select your log text and click it.

Comment: Useful! I've added the log and removed the timestamp info. "2013/08/21 15:30:01:071 EDT [DEBUG]"

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but shouldn't you be adding all of the headers?
Some of the calls are setHeader:

```
putRequest.addHeader("Version", version);
putRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", content);
```

Should be:

```
putRequest.addHeader("Version", version);
putRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", content);
```

Comment: I remember in the case of this API, the headers were desired but not necessary. That actually, providing the headers was breaking the application due to a bug in the underlying language (Business Basic w/Java) the API was written in. I've long since ran way from that!