# Android: HttpPost setEntity does not work

Tags: php, android

I want to add NameValuePairs to an HttpPost that calls a php-script (to query a database).

Here's what I've tried:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("w", "(id='1a')"));
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.tv/getList.php");
UrlEncodedFormEntity requestEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);             
httpPost.addHeader(requestEntity.getContentType());
httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I expect to only get the element with id=1a but the script returns all elements. If I call the php like that:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.tv/getList.php?w=(id='1a')");
```

It works perfectly fine.

Am I doing something wrong when setting the NameValueParis? Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your content type for request that you have set in header

Comment: @PramodYadav I've tried both "text/plain" and "application/json"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028981/using-httpclient-and-httppost-in-android-with-post-parameters refer this link once

Comment: @Ram thank you. That's what I've had originally I only added the contentType stuff because someone on SO suggested it. Still does not work.